# os x process state UE

Tags: macos, process, state

I've got process running that can't be killed. It's my EyeTV App and here is what 'ps aux' says:

```
cb0      87583   1,0  3,4   812796 144236   ??  UE   21Nov09 2638:11.45 [.....]/EyeTV
```

The process state is really strange as I've never seen UE before. The manpage tells me

---

> *U means Marks a process in uninterruptible wait*
>
> *E means The process is trying to exit*

---

But I'm not able to kill the process. Any Idea how I could force it to exit??

Additional Info: None of the following statments worked:

- kill -S KILL
- kill -S QUIT
- kill -2
- kill -9

Comment: Are you able to kill it with Force Quite (outside bash session)?

Comment: I really don't know. It's been nearly 4 years ago :)
But I'm sure I also tried this option.

Comment: To bad there were no follow ups on this. 9 years now and can't find to much info on it. I did a fresh Catalina install (because of errors like this) and I still didn't get rid of it. It's mostly related to electron apps for me, just fyi.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using

```
top
```

in order to get all active processes, and then

```
kill(PID)
```

where PID will be referring to the EyeTV process ID handed to you by top?
Also (and I am not sure this works two, but it just might), you could try

```
kill(pid,SIGTERM)
```

which sends a termination signal to the process (however that is used in C programming to kill a process, so I am not 100% sure it would work outside of the programming language, but worth a try)

Comment: I'm sure I tried this but it was nearly 5 years and I can not reproduce it any more.